# Cannot read property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to zoom images when I click on it. I use thymleaf as engine to display my images

```
<div th:each="pic : ${pjWrapper.cars}" class="col-md-55">
  <div class="image view view-first">
    <img th:id="${'img_' + picStat.index}" th:src="${pic.url}" alt="image" />
    <div class="mask" th:id="${picStat.index}" onclick="zoom(event)">
      <p  th:text="${pic.name}">&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="tools tools-bottom">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="img-zoom-modal" class="img-zoom-modal">
  <span class="img-zoom-close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="modalImg">
  <div id="img-zoom-caption"></div>
</div>
```

This is the JS function that I use

```
function zoom(e) {
    var modal = document.querySelector("#img-zoom-modal");
    var img = document.querySelector('#img_' + e.target.id);
    var modalImg = document.querySelector('#modalImg');
    var captionText = document.querySelector('#img-zoom-caption');
    
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;    // THIS LINE RETURN ERROR  img is null
    captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("img-zoom-close")[0];
    
    modal.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

When I click more times on different images I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null` in the line above `modalImg.src = img.src`

I'm inspired by this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Do you have any idea why I get this error ?

Comment: You get this error because `document.querySelector('#img_' + e.target.id);` is `null`. That means no element with that id is found.

Comment: I confirm that the element was generated correctly and it's present in the html

Comment: I would try to debuging it and add `console.log( document.querySelector('#img_' + e.target.id), #img_' + e.target.id`). Right now I don't see why the img variable should be null then.

Comment: Oh wait I see, `e.target` does not have to be the div you bound the click event to. So `e.target.id` is not what you want it to be. Changing it to `e.currentTarget.id` should fix the problem. [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: It works using `e.currentTarget.id` . Thank you